# How to send email from server/cPanel with angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, cpanel

I have an angular application with a contact form. On user submitting the contact form I want to automatically send an email to myself with the users inputs.

Is it possible to send the email from the server or cPanel using only angular? How?

If not; what is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER:**

No, it is not possible to "send the email from the server or cPanel using only angular". Angular is limited to front-end only.

**THE SOLUTION:**

Implement a server-side application (in my case [node js](https://nodejs.org/en/)) on the shared server allowing me to write server-side code.

**SENDING DATA FROM ANGULAR APPLICATION TO NODE JS:**

Import [HttpClientModule](https://angular.io/guide/http) to angulars app.module.ts

Import [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) to the typescript file I wanted to send data from allowing me to "POST" the users contact data to the newly implemented [node js](https://nodejs.org/en/) application.

```
this.http.post('/send', f.value)
  .subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

**SENDING THE EMAIL:**

Upon the [node js](https://nodejs.org/en/) application receiving the data I used [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) and some stock standard code to create and send an email using [SMTP protocol.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)

**RESULTS:**

The code for both the angular and node js apps will be posted shortly on [GitHub](https://github.com/JimmyDevGit/JamesEllisDev) and the finished product can be found at [JamesEllisDev.com](https://jamesellisdev.com).